# How to search a value in the same page by clickable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

http://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html
in this example has two tables and Table2 is an own searched page. And I want to make a page like `<a href` and click it to search button takes value automatically.

```
    >$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
        } );

        $('table.table').DataTable( {
            ajax:           '../ajax/data/arrays.txt',
            scrollY:        200,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging:         false
        } );


    // Apply a search to the second table for the demo
$('#myTable2').DataTable().search( 'New York' ).draw(); } );
```

**This jQuery has that line**

> $('#myTable2').DataTable().search( 'New York' ).draw(); } );

**I want it clickable and I couldn't find any examples for hours**

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to add a click handler to the `<td>` elements of `#myTable1`.

Select the elements:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable1 > td');
```

Loop through them and add a click listener:

```
for(var ix = 0, length = elements.length; ix < length; ix++) {
    elements[ix].addEventListener('click', onElementClick);
}
```

Then, write a function to take the value of the clicked element and create the second table:

```
function onElementClick() {
    $('#myTable2').DataTable().search( this.value ).draw(); } );
}
```

This is totally untested and I probably have a mistake or two, but that's probably what I would try since I'm too lazy to read all of the DataTables documentation. :D

Ok, I had a couple of bugs. In your JS Bin, change your JavaScript to this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $("#search").click(function() {
    table.search("rhona").draw();
  });

  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#example td');

  for(var ix = 0, length = elements.length; ix < length; ix++) {
    elements[ix].addEventListener('click', onElementClick);
  }

  function onElementClick() {
    table.search(this.innerText).draw();
  }
});
```

Comment: I am still trying to testing it and I wanna ask that. What should I do after search to make search button blank? For example put the clear button near the search button?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'll have to read the DataTable documentation to find out how to clear a search. If I had to guess, probably `table.draw();`.

Comment: this is my javascript. I cant edit your js to my javascript can you please edit it?     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
    } );
     
 $('table.table').DataTable({
    "order": [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    paging: true,
    "oLanguage": {
      "sUrl": "js/dil/Turkish.json",
    }
    } );
 
    // Apply a search to the second table for the demo
    $('#myTable2').DataTable();
} );

Comment: You might need to update your question with the specific, verifiable problem that you are having. StackOverflow is not a [code writing service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service).